# what's wrong with this mysql query..?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `a`.`aID` INNER JOIN `a` ON `a`.`aID` = `b`.`aID` FROM `b` WHERE 1;

**ERROR 1064** - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN `a` ON `a`.`aID`  at 
line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**From** clause muse come before **join** statement.

**Where 1** also has no meaning. It displays all details
try

```
SELECT 
    a.aID
FROM
    b
        INNER JOIN
    a ON a.aID = b.aID;
```

Comment: 'WHERE 1' has no meaning, but it does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote wrong syntax.

Try this

```
SELECT a.aID 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b ON a.aID = b.aID;
```

Answer (score 0):

your entire query is wrong you should try like this

```
SELECT a.aId FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.aID=b.aID WHERE 1;
```